# Dataframe isn't sorted in Graph

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe with about 1 million rows. Now I sort them by the column 'mittlere Wind', afterwards I want to plot the Graph. The old order is still used in the graphic. What am I doing wrong?

```
df.sort_values("mittlere Wind", axis = 0, ascending = True, 
                 inplace = True, na_position ='last')

plt.plot(df["mittlere Leistung"],'ro',markersize=np.sqrt(0.02), label ="mittlere Leistung19",color='orange' )
plt.plot(df["plus"],'ro',markersize=np.sqrt(0.02), label ="plus" , color='green')
plt.plot(df["minus"], 'ro',markersize=np.sqrt(0.02),label ="minus",color='red' )
```

Comment: try this : df=df.sort_values("mittlere Wind", axis = 0, ascending = True, 
                 inplace = True, na_position ='last')
Please accept my apologies if it doesn't work

Comment: This excatly what I did :D but still, thanks for your respond.